# Ubuntu 22.04 ubuntu Adsys failed to update GPO

Tags: ubuntu, gpo

can anyone point me to correct direction.

I successfully configure LDAP integration with Ubuntu 22.04 with Win 2022
Using RealmD.

Here are the steps i did.

```
sudo apt install sssd-ad sssd-tools realmd adcli

sudo realm join mylab.com

sudo realm list
mylab.com
  type: kerberos
  realm-name: MYLAB.COM
  domain-name: mylab.com
  configured: kerberos-member
  server-software: active-directory
  client-software: sssd
  required-package: sssd-tools
  required-package: sssd
  required-package: libnss-sss
  required-package: libpam-sss
  required-package: adcli
  required-package: samba-common-bin
  login-formats: %U@mylab.com
  login-policy: allow-realm-logins
```

here is the SSSD.conf

```
[sssd]
domains = mylab.com
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/mylab.com]
default_shell = /bin/bash
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
cache_credentials = True
krb5_realm = MYLAB.COM
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli 
id_provider = ad
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
ad_domain = mylab.com
use_fully_qualified_names = True
ldap_id_mapping = True
access_provider = ad
ad_gpo_access_control = permissive
```

So far, from this point i can login using AD accounts.

After installing the adsys, and generate ADMX,ADML file and uploading to AD Sysvol,
and apply GPO, thats where I get this errors:

```
sudo adsysctl policy update

ERROR Error from server: error while updating policy: no domain provided for user "root" and no default domain in sssd.conf

su -l son.goku@mylab.com
Applying machine settings
ERROR Error from server: error while updating policy: can't get policies for "linuxlab4": machine is offline and policies cache is unavailable: can't get cached policies from /var/cache/adsys/policies/linuxlab4: open /var/cache/adsys/policies/linuxlab4/policies: no such file or directory 
su: cannot open session: Failure setting user credentials
```

i tried googling but there is not enough information regarding this error.
One article said that Ubuntu Pro only support ADSYS, though i haven't tried Ubuntu Pro.